# Drawing two spheres separated by horizontal distance along z axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

I would like to draw another sphere like the following one, including axes, lines and angles (all of them "primed"), but shifted by (0,0,5), that is, displaced by 5 along z axis.

I want to have both spheres in the same tikzpicture. I have tried a lot of things, but none worked perfectly. One of my problems is that the `\shade` command uses screen coordinates (`tdplot_screen_coords`), which makes hard to center the second sphere at (0,0,5) exactly. I have also tried `\tdplotsetrotatedcoordsorigin{(Shift)}`, but I couldn't shift all elements with it.

How can I draw that second sphere? I'm almost giving it up and building the image with OpenGL.

[image: Sphere with spherical coordinates]

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110}
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{-90}{-90}{0}
%
\resizebox{10cm}{!}%
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3,tdplot_rotated_coords]
  % Origens e pontos:
  \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
  % Eixos na origem 1:
  \draw[thick,->] (O) -- (1.5,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
  \draw[thick,->] (O) -- (0,1.5,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
  \draw[thick,->] (O) -- (0,0,1.5) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
  % 
  \def\rvec{1}
  \def\thetavec{45}
  \def\phivec{30}
  %
  \tdplotsetcoord{P}{\rvec}{\thetavec}{\phivec}
  % Preencher esfera 1:
  \shade[tdplot_screen_coords, ball color = white, opacity=.5]     (0,0,0) circle (\rvec);
  % Linha da origem ao ponto:
  \draw[-stealth,color=red] (O) -- (P) node[above right] {$P$};
  % Linhas aos planos:
  \draw[dashed, color=red] (O) -- (Pxy);
  \draw[dashed, color=red] (P) -- (Pxy);
  % Angulos:
  \tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(O)}{0.2}{0}{\phivec}{anchor=north east}{$\phi$}
  \tdplotsetrotatedthetaplanecoords{\phivec}
  \tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(O)}{0.5}{0}{\thetavec}{anchor=south west}{$\theta$}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you want. This places a second shaded circle at `(0,0,5)` relative to the rotated coordinate system i.e. at `(0,5,0)` relative to the main coordinate system.

I've added thin blue axes to show those of the main coordinate system and thin green axes for those of the translated rotated coordinate system relative to which the additional circle is drawn. Obviously these are just included for explanatory purposes.

[image: main, rotated and translated rotated coordinate systems]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110}
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{-90}{-90}{0}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3,tdplot_main_coords]
  \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
  \coordinate (o) at (0,5,0);
  \draw [->, blue, thin] (O) -- (1.75,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
  \draw [->, blue, thin] (O) -- (0,1.75,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
  \draw [->, blue, thin] (O) -- (0,0,1.75) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
  \begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
    \draw [thick,->] (O) -- (1.5,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
    \draw [thick,->] (O) -- (0,1.5,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
    \draw [thick,->] (O) -- (0,0,1.5) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
    \def\rvec{1}
    \def\thetavec{45}
    \def\phivec{30}
    \tdplotsetcoord{P}{\rvec}{\thetavec}{\phivec}
    \shade[tdplot_screen_coords, ball color = white, opacity=.5] (0,0,0) circle (\rvec);
    \draw[-stealth, color=red] (O) -- (P) node[above right] {$P$};
    \draw[dashed, color=red] (O) -- (Pxy);
    \draw[dashed, color=red] (P) -- (Pxy);
    \tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(O)}{0.2}{0}{\phivec}{anchor=north east}{$\phi$}
    \tdplotsetrotatedthetaplanecoords{\phivec}
    \tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(O)}{0.5}{0}{\thetavec}{anchor=south west}{$\theta$}
  \end{scope}
  \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{-90}{-90}{0}
  \tdplotsetrotatedcoordsorigin{(o)}
  \begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
    \draw [thin, green, ->] (o) -- (1.5,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
    \draw [thin, green, ->] (o) -- (0,1.5,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
    \draw [thin, green, ->] (o) -- (0,0,1.5) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
    \def\rvec{1}
    \shade[tdplot_screen_coords, ball color = white, opacity=.5] (0,0,0) circle (\rvec);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, this is just equivalent to

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3,tdplot_main_coords]
  \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
  \coordinate (o) at (0,5,0);
  \draw [->, blue, thin] (O) -- (1.75,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
  \draw [->, blue, thin] (O) -- (0,1.75,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
  \draw [->, blue, thin] (O) -- (0,0,1.75) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
  \begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
    \draw [thick,->] (O) -- (1.5,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
    \draw [thick,->] (O) -- (0,1.5,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
    \draw [thick,->] (O) -- (0,0,1.5) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
    \def\rvec{1}
    \def\thetavec{45}
    \def\phivec{30}
    \tdplotsetcoord{P}{\rvec}{\thetavec}{\phivec}
    \shade[tdplot_screen_coords, ball color = white, opacity=.5] (0,0,0) circle (\rvec);
    \draw[-stealth, color=red] (O) -- (P) node[above right] {$P$};
    \draw[dashed, color=red] (O) -- (Pxy);
    \draw[dashed, color=red] (P) -- (Pxy);
    \tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(O)}{0.2}{0}{\phivec}{anchor=north east}{$\phi$}
    \tdplotsetrotatedthetaplanecoords{\phivec}
    \tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(O)}{0.5}{0}{\thetavec}{anchor=south west}{$\theta$}
  \end{scope}
  \shade[tdplot_screen_coords, ball color = white, opacity=.5] (o) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

except that I have not added green axes as the coordinate system is neither rotated nor translated in this case.

[image: main and rotated coordinate systems]

I included the first version simply because you might really want something like this

[image: two complete circle thingies]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3,tdplot_main_coords]
  \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
  \coordinate (o) at (0,5,0);
  \draw [->, blue, thin] (O) -- (1.75,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
  \draw [->, blue, thin] (O) -- (0,1.75,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
  \draw [->, blue, thin] (O) -- (0,0,1.75) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
  \begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
    \draw [thick,->] (O) -- (1.5,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
    \draw [thick,->] (O) -- (0,1.5,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
    \draw [thick,->] (O) -- (0,0,1.5) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
    \def\rvec{1}
    \def\thetavec{45}
    \def\phivec{30}
    \tdplotsetcoord{P}{\rvec}{\thetavec}{\phivec}
    \shade[tdplot_screen_coords, ball color = white, opacity=.5] (0,0,0) circle (\rvec);
    \draw[-stealth, color=red] (O) -- (P) node[above right] {$P$};
    \draw[dashed, color=red] (O) -- (Pxy);
    \draw[dashed, color=red] (P) -- (Pxy);
    \tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(O)}{0.2}{0}{\phivec}{anchor=north east}{$\phi$}
    \tdplotsetrotatedthetaplanecoords{\phivec}
    \tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(O)}{0.5}{0}{\thetavec}{anchor=south west}{$\theta$}
  \end{scope}
  \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{-90}{-90}{0}
  \tdplotsetrotatedcoordsorigin{(o)}
  \begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
    \draw [thin, green, ->] (o) -- (1.5,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
    \draw [thin, green, ->] (o) -- (0,1.5,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
    \draw [thin, green, ->] (o) -- (0,0,1.5) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
    \def\rvec{1}
    \def\thetavec{45}
    \def\phivec{30}
    \tdplotsetcoord{P}{\rvec}{\thetavec}{\phivec}
    \shade[tdplot_screen_coords, ball color = white, opacity=.5] (o) circle (\rvec);
    \draw [-stealth, color=red] (o) -- (P) node[above right] {$P$};
    \draw [dashed, color=red] (o) -- (Pxy);
    \draw [dashed, color=red] (P) -- (Pxy);
    \tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(o)}{0.2}{0}{\phivec}{anchor=north east}{$\phi$}
    \tdplotsetrotatedthetaplanecoords{\phivec}
    \tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(o)}{0.5}{0}{\thetavec}{anchor=south west}{$\theta$}
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want. It would be nice to have a simple way of drawing a sphere define in `tdplot_rotated_coords` or `tdplot_main_coords` instead of `tdplot_screen_coords`, but it seems TikZ doesn't have actual 3D solids. As you see, the y axis (unrotated coordinate x axis) doesn't goes out the sphere as it should (while the other axes become thicker as they go out the sphere). I know there are codes to draw spheres, but not a `\sphere[coordinate-system]{radius}{x}{y}{z}` command.

Comment: Yes, well. You are not drawing a sphere here - just shading a circle - so it is not going to look much like a sphere. There are questions showing how to draw spheres, as you say. But, in truth, for 3D, there are better options than TikZ.